# Validación de solo letras C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy aprendiendo y necesito validar que al ingresar por consola sólo permita ingresar letras, ya logré esto pero entonces se presenta el siguiente probelma y es que necesito usar el ciclo `Do {}(while)` para que salga hasta que solo ingrese una letra,no sé como hacer para que quede pidiendo la letra hasta que realmente se ingrese una.
Quisiera una ayuda o saber si existe otra manera de validar que se ingresen solo letras sin el método que estoy utilizando

```
string letra = string.Empty;

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una letra.");
                    letra = Console.ReadLine();

                if (IsLetters(letra))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Son letras.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No son letras.");
                }    
                Console.WriteLine($"La letra es: {letra}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }    
        private static bool IsLetters(string letra)
        {
            foreach (Char ch in letra)
            {
                if (!Char.IsLetter(ch) && ch!=32)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }    
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo que necesitas es iterar y pedir por consola una letra mientras la cadena ingresada no sea una letra. Cuando el usuario ingrese una letra terminara el ciclo. Podes hacerlo de esta forma usando el metodo que tenes:

```
    public void ValidarLetra()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una letra.");
        string letra = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!IsLetters(letra)) { //mientras no sea una letra sigo iterando
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una letra.");
            letra = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"La letra es: {letra}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que ingrese SOLO una letra, deberías usar `Console.ReadKey()` y no `Console.ReadLine()`. Luego con la propiedad `KeyChar` de puedes obtener el `char` de la tecla pulsada y validar que sea una letra con el método `IsLetter` de `Char`. Te dejo un ejemplo con el do while que querías.

```
char letra;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce una letra: ");
    letra = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
while (!Char.IsLetter(letra));
```

Answer (score 0):

En la accion KeyPress poner este metodo

```
    public void validarLetras(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;

        }
    }
```